# Connecting to Oracle WebLogic Server Instance (Admin Server)

Tags: oracle, command-line, webserver, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I have just started playing around with Oracle Weblogic. I am trying to do some scripting using WLST , a commandline tool. I have a test environment set up which has **Weblogic 10.3 and Linux 2.6.18** on it. **I have managed to log into wlst in the offline/interactive mode.**

**I now want to connect to the AdminServer in my domain. I am having issues doing so.**

Following is the command that I am using:

```
    wls:/offline> connect('username','password','localhost:7002')
```

Once the command is fired it just shows the cursor blinking and the operation does not timeout.

Using the console I have verified the state of the AdminServer , the user defined in security realm and the listen port of the server.

I am wondering why the above command did not work.

On the other hand I created a test managed server using the administration console and successfully made a connection through wlst using the same command.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Try giving 't3://localhost:7002' as the third parameter for connect command.

Comment: That's the first one i tried out. It does not work. Figured out that the parameter 'localhost:7002' defaults to the t3 protocol unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Is a firewall active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two things.

On a default installation, port 7002 is a ssl port. It might not be configured and to use it you should specify the **t3s** protocol, instead of using default t3.

Also, the server is not listening on `localhost`. That server has an IP address, and chances are the admin server bound to it. It is not listening to 127.0.0.1.

To tell, issue this command (Linux):

```
#Linux
netstat -plan | grep 7001.*LISTEN 

REM Windows
netstat -a -p tcp -n -o | findstr /R 7001.*LISTENING
```

You will see something like this (Linux):

```
tcp   0    0 ::ffff:192.168.1.11:7001   :::*     LISTEN      20993/java
```

You can use the IP address, but might as well use the fully qualified name given by:

```
nslookup 192.168.1.11
```

Try again connecting :

```
connect('username','password','t3://myserver-fqdn.example.com:7001')
```

Or if SSL is configured, this should work:

```
connect('username','password','t3s://myserver-fqdn.example.com:7002')
```

Answer (score 0):

Mohan there could be missing in /etc/hosts file. Please check that other reason could be firewall on the Linux box would making issue.
can you show your connect command for managed server? That may hint us to identify issue.

Did you tried with the 1p addresss as well with t3:// protocol?